# Book about a woman named Lessa

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

There were dragons, and she could talk to them. I remember the author's name being Anne maybe. I also think that the author may be dead. I read the first book in this series some years ago. I remember there being green dragons as the 'lowest' rank followed by blue, then brown, then bronze and finally gold. Any help appreciated!!!

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 39):

Look for Anne McCaffrey's "[DragonRiders of Pern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000RH0E70)" Trilogy, "Dragon Drums Trilogy" and a few others (25 books are listed on Amazon).

Lessa, in particular, shows up in [about half of the books](https://pern.fandom.com/wiki/Lessa#Appearances) either as the protagonist or a supporting character, and the draconic heirarchy you describe and ability to communicate with dragons are two of the main setting features of the series.

The main character of the first novel, *Dragonflight*, is named Lessa, who is discovered living in the hold's watchwher (essentially a big, doglike lizard) house by the dragonrider sent to investigate the death of the Lord Holder, Fax, when his dragon overhears her thoughts as she tries to calm the watchwher down telepathically. It turns out that she is able to communicate with all dragons (and their relatives).

Lessa is Weyrwoman of Benden Weyr, and shows up in several books in the series.

- *The Masterharper of Pern*
- *Dragonflight*
- *Dragonquest*
- *Dragonsong*
- *Dragonsinger* (mention)
- *Dragondrums*
- *The White Dragon*
- *The Renegades of Pern*
- *The Girl Who Heard Dragons*
- *Dragon's Code*
- *All the Weyrs of Pern*
- *The Dolphins of Pern*
- *The Skies of Pern*
- *The People of Pern*
- *Moreta: DragonLady of Pern*

Comment: [Cover art by Michael Whelan](https://www.michaelwhelan.com/anne-mccaffrey/)

Comment: This is absolutely the Pern books. Dragonflight is her origin story, well worth starting there

Comment: Some of your details are incorrect - in particular, Fax isn't dead (yet) when F'lar arrives. (I'd say more about it, but it'd be a major spoiler.)